# Does capacitance value affect ripple voltage, or does something else?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I was reading TI's *Designing an LLC Resonant Half-Bridge Converter* when I came across this paragraph:

[image]

Does the actual capacitance value not really matter, or is this just the case for the LLC half-bridge?

Comment: I think this ignores changes in load current due to the definition of ripple.

Comment: This is a small-ripple approximation where by definition C >> 1 / (2 pi F R).  You will need at least as much capacitance to meet this, but the ripple voltage will be somewhat higher as a result anyway, and somewhat lower ESR, and higher C, will be required in the end.

Comment: Are you saying to choose C such that it's resulting impedance is much lower than the impedance from the ESR?

Comment: There's a component of ripple that depends on C, the load current, and the switching frequency, but there's a much larger component (in any converter with sufficient capacitance) that depends on ESR and ripple current. As long as C is high enough, you can ignore the first component and focus only on the second. (there's yet another component that depends on the capacitor's ESL as well, that usually isn't a concern in practical circuits but causes headaches in simulations. You can probably ignore that one.)

Comment: It's noteworthy what permits the assumption: electrolytics generally have more ESR than Xc at SMPS frequencies, and less ripple current ratings than would permit using minimum C values. So you end up using much, much more than strictly required, and as a result, you can kinda ignore Xc. Note this probably isn't true if you're using mostly ceramic or film!